# Magento Order Missing

Tags: orders

A client placed an order on our site twice in one day, but the order never came through on the Magento side.  It did get processed successfully through Heartland payments, though.  Any idea on why this order is missing?  I did see the order in the databased sales_flat_quote, but I wasn't sure why it was there and no where else.  Please help.

Comment: Please check Magento and Apache logs and the report directory in var for any specific errors that might give us more information

Comment: Is the order in sales_flat_order ?

Comment: It is possible that your filters are set in admin